# How to overwrite the urlconf without specifying a "path.to.urls"?

Tags: python, django

Both django-hosts and this solution ([Django: Overwrite ROOT_URLCONF with request.urlconf in middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928501/django-overwrite-root-urlconf-with-request-urlconf-in-middleware)), advises to use Middleware to override the URLConf by specifying the path for the urlconf.

However, that would require a file with the variable "urlpatterns".

Instead, what I'm trying to do is that, loading the urlpatterns based on the subdomain/project. So I'm looking for someway to do it without generating a file everytime someone update the pages' URL and writing it to a file "urls_subdomain.py".

Here's the reference to the request middleware by django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

Comment: can you try this https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts

Comment: yes, but it is not dynamic. you need to create a file for it.